# Displaying bulleted centered list

Tags: html, css, list, bulletedlist

I'm having a problem displaying a bulleted list like what is on the image attachment link. I've already tried almost possible CSS combination but unable to achieve what I want:[image]

My code goes something like this:

```css
.sunco-listed {
  width: 500px;
}

.sunco-listed ul {
  text-align: center;
}

.sunco-listed li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 25px;
} 

.sunco-listed li:nth-child(1) {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sunco-listed">
  <ul>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any assistance/help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`flex` on the parent will retain the list-item bullets, with `justify-content: center` and `flex-wrap: wrap` so they'll wrap with the limited width, then use `:first-child` and `:last-child` for the first/last effect.

```css
.sunco-listed {
  width: 500px;
}

.sunco-listed ul {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sunco-listed li {
  padding-right: 25px;
} 

.sunco-listed li:first-child {
  list-style: none;
}

.sunco-listed li:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sunco-listed">
  <ul>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
    <li>Spare parts 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment/help. Is this using  a flexbox? I don't have any experience/knowledge using it though. But heard a lot of good views about it.

Comment: @BryLedesma yes, here's a good guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Oh thanks for that helpful resource about flexbox too. I'll have a look into this one as well during my available spare time.